# Can I change local environment variables for a running process?

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Suppose I have a continuous process running that reads an environment variable:

```
export APPLE=abc123
watch echo \$APPLE
```

Now, is there any way to change the value that's being read during execution?  I've tried suspending the process (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>), exporting a new value for the variable, then resuming (`fg`), but the old value is still displayed.

Is this possible?  I'd prefer an answer that works with basic command-line tools and doesn't require specialized software, though requiring root privileges is OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've tried suspending the process (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>), exporting a new value for the variable, then resuming (`fg`), but the old value is still displayed.

This does not work because environment variables are *inherited when the process starts* – but  when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> and `fg` it doesn't restart `watch`; it just pauses and unpauses the old process.

The only way to change the environment for a running process, from the outside, is to do it *from inside the process* with a debugging tool. For example:

```
$ gdb -p $(pidof watch)
(gdb) p setenv("APPLE", "orange")
(gdb) q
Really detach? y
```

Comment: I get this error: `No symbol "setenv" in current context`. On Mac Sierra